# snmp OID not increasing

Tags: snmp, oid

I try to create a custom SNMP oid (and script).

I add the following line to snmpd.conf (and restart service) :

```
pass .1.3.6.1.3.2 /bin/myscript.sh
```

.

```
cat myscript.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo .1.3.6.1.3.2
echo gauge
exec 100
```

.

```
snmpwalk -c mycommunity -v2c 10.2.1.4 .1.3.6.1.3.2
SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.2 = Gauge32: 100
Error: OID not increasing: SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.2
>= SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.2
```

Is snmpwalk expecting anything at the end of the query ? snmpget work with no problem!

Answer (score 5):

By default snmpwalk expect the value to be increasing. To get around it try:

```
snmpwalk -Cc -c mycommunity -v2c 10.2.1.4 .1.3.6.1.3.2
```

The Cc option does this:
"do not check returned OIDs are increasing"

Often the walk can be completed with oid:s out of order using this.

Answer (score 2):

`snmpwalk` expects increasing replies :

```
SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.2 = Gauge32: 100
SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.3 = Gauge32: 1125
SNMPv2-SMI::other.1 = Gauge32: 10
END
```

It appears that the *snmp agent* replies two identical values :

```
SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.2 = Gauge32: 100
SNMPv2-SMI::experimental.2 = Gauge32: 100
```

So it fails (unexpected behaviour).